# Python open vs file

Tags: python, file-io

I see people occasionally open a file handler with the `file` built in; Particularly in the [pyyaml documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation).

This confuses me as the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) states:

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking this constructor directly. file is more suited to type testing (for example, writing isinstance(f, file)).

So this seems to imply that `file` and `open` do the same thing, yet `file` is a type, whereas `open` is a function:

```
>>> open
<built-in function open>
>>> file
<type 'file'>
```

And they both return a `file` type object:

```
>>> open('/dev/zero')
<open file '/dev/zero', mode 'r' at 0x7f9bb0b964b0>
>>> file('/dev/zero')
<open file '/dev/zero', mode 'r' at 0x7f9bb0b96540>
```

---

Is there a difference of using one or the other?

Are there caveats or advantages to using `file` vs `open` to open files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do the same thing. Using one versus the other is simply a matter of style and readability; there are no other caveats or advantages in terms of behavior.

Comment: Not quite true; `open` allows you to use it as a contextmanager in a `with` statement so that the file is properly closed reguardless of errors in your code that deals with that file.

Comment: `open` is a preferable way (factory vs constructor), besides, `file` was removed since 3.0. And, @aruisdante, `file` can also be used in context managers.

Comment: @bereal huh, sure enough it can. But I completely agree with your point about using a factory vs. a concrete type constructor, especially in a duck-typed dynamic language like Python.